# Identifying a class which "works on an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, static

A static class should not work on an instance of an object. What then, identifies an instance of an object being "worked on"? Would this be anything concrete (i.e. pass in new ObjectA() to a a method's parameters). So if this is what I see, the class should not be static.

Thanks

Comment: This question is too vague.  Can you provide a code example?

Comment: Not sure what your question is... Some sort of guideline from somewhere?  i.e. extension methods sort of "work on an instance of an object" by design.

Comment: everything works on an instance of some object - it's too wild and doesn't sound like it makes much sense, though outside the context

Comment: Try to explain it in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>A static class simply means that there is only ONE instance of that object.</strike> A Static class simply behaves AS IF there was only one instance of it. Think of it as global; you cannot instantiate any objects of a static class. The values of member variable of the class will retain their value globally and you can 'work' on them with member functions.

As opposed to a static class, with a non-static class you can create new objects and 'work' on these objects with member functions:

```
vehicle honda = new vehicle();
honda.fuelup(10);
honda.value.ToString();
```

If this were to be a static class:

```
vehicle.fuelup(10);
vehicle.value.ToString();
```

In the above example we created an object honda, of class type vehicle. We then 'worked' on the object with functions. For the static class, we <strike>didn't need to</strike> cannot create an object, we just call the class name instead of the object name (like honda).

To recap:

- <strike>Static = global, one instance</strike>
- Static = global, **AS IF** it was only one instance (the program itelf?)
- Non-static = local scope, many instances

If this doesn't answer or address the question, please rephrase it with a clear question.

Comment: This is wrong info, a static class cannot be instantiated, and it is not a "one instance only class".

Comment: @marcof is correct, static classes do not have instances.  Static means that the members are associated with the type, not an instance.

Comment: That is correct and I apologize if i mislead. I should have written this differently: A static class works AS IF it was just one instance. I think the idea of a "static class" may be to simply give "global functions" to a program. I'm not certain if some object is created behind the scenes (i doubt it). Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I corrected the answer as i did contradict myself on the first sentence, then stating that you cannot instanticate a static class. So much for posting without sleep :)